# add external jars in spring - java

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, hadoop

I am new to spring, I am trying a simple web dynamic application getting data from database and showing on front end using impala.
This is connector class :

```
private static final String IMPALAD_HOST = "host";
private static final String IMPALAD_JDBC_PORT = "port";

private static final String CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:hive2://" + IMPALAD_HOST + ':' + IMPALAD_JDBC_PORT + "/;auth=noSasl";
private static final String JDBC_DRIVER_NAME = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException{
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER_NAME);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL,"","");
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}`
```

HIve-connector jar is added in the java build path in eclipse. getConnection() works if i call it from a main method of a java class, but getConnection() gives hive driver not found exception if i call this method from jsp page. :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

Comment: no, i tried in simple j2ee project having same prob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not having the `hive-jdbc.jar` in your webapplication archive. i.e. war file. it is being missed while packaging the application.You should place it in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory. Please also ensure that you also add it in the deployment assembly of the eclipse project.

It works when you run the main class because the `hive-jdbc.jar` is configured in the build path. It is different from webapplication perspective.

Note: `ClassNotFoundException` shouldn't be thrown unless you are going to handle it. You should have all the required jars in your application package during runtime in classpath.

Comment: @Naveen Glad, It helped. Please accept the answer to let others know that this question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong Driver-Class. 
Use `org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`instead.

Comment: this is for hive, i am connecting to impala which uses hive thrift server, issue is solved i had to add jars in weContent/lib folder